# pyaudio is not found

Tags: python, speech-recognition

```
def takeCommand():
 r=sr.Recognizer()
 with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print("Listing ...")
    r.pause_threshold =1
    audio=r.listen(source)
 try:
    print("Recongnizing.....")
    query=r.recognize_google(audio,language='en-in')
    print(f"User said: {query}")

 except Exception as e:
    # print(e)
    print("Say again please")
    return "none"
 return query
if __name__=="__main__":
  takeCommand()
```

Error:-
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\python38\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition_*init*_.py", line 108, in get_pyaudio
import pyaudio
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyaudio'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:/Users/dhruv/Desktop/pythonProject/siri/siri.py", line 40, in 
takeCommand()
File "c:/Users/dhruv/Desktop/pythonProject/siri/siri.py", line 24, in takeCommand
with sr.Microphone() as source:
File "C:\python38\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition_*init*_.py", line 79, in **init**
self.pyaudio_module = self.get_pyaudio()
File "C:\python38\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition_*init*_.py", line 110, in get_pyaudio
raise AttributeError("Could not find PyAudio; check installation")
AttributeError: Could not find PyAudio; check installation

Comment: Did you install pyaudio? See http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/. On windows: `python -m pip install pyaudio`

Comment: Please share what you've tried.